# Multiple history push for rerendering a component in react?

Tags: reactjs

Can I refresh my component Message by putting history.push('/') and history.push('/message') in action in redux-action?

Comment: Its not a good way, why did you want to refresh the page? If it is state you can use store of redux or useState of react hooks.

Comment: The component has pagination and each page have 10 table-rows and each row has a button for deleting it. Suppose I delete the 2nd, 3rd, 4th row and remove then from the Redux reducer data array , then it will show only 7 item in 1st page instead of 10 and 10 item in page 2 which is incorrect. That why I am trying to render the component with a new get call.

Comment: show me the code. you send new state in the reducer?